# How to change the HTML layout of an existing WebPart?

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-online

I'm using Sharepoint Online, and there's quite a few WebParts available by default: RSS Reader, document viewer, forum...

I see that editing the source in Sharepoint Designer, I have some more control on how to filter/organize the content displayed by the WebPart, however, I haven't found any way to directly change how it is displayed.

I see that I can also create and upload my own WebParts using Visual Studio. Can I perhaps use Visual Studio to edit some of the existing WebParts that Sharepoint Online provide ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet, especially with being on Office 365, is to use JavaScript and CSS techniques to manipulate the web part. You can rearrange and change the display of the web part to almost anything you can imagine.

You cannot manipulate the web part in Visual Studio and then upload to SPOnline. You can create new App parts, using the App Model. That's the only way to get custom web parts, aka app parts, into SPOnline. If you were using SharePoint on-prem, you might be able to hack through something and install a farm feature to override the web parts.

Comment: We were thinking of using JS and CSS as a last resort solution... I guess we'll have to do just that (or make our own App Parts when relevant). Thanks for the answer !